# problem with ActionMailer configuration in setup_email.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I spent several days trying to get this work => I would like to send email from my application **localhost**, **without** using gmail or other mail server, so I tried this:

in **/config/initializers/setup_email.rb**

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "localhost",
    :port => 25
}
```

But I got "**Connection refused - connect(2)**" error message like following:

```
Connection refused - connect(2)
/home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p330/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:551:in `initialize'
/home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p330/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:551:in `open'
/home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p330/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:551:in `do_start'
/home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p330/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:67:in `timeout'
/home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p330/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:101:in `timeout'
/home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p330/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:551:in `do_start'
/home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p330/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:525:in `start'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@myapp/gems/mail-2.2.15/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:127:in `deliver!'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@myapp/gems/mail-2.2.15/lib/mail/message.rb:1967:in `do_delivery'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@myapp/gems/mail-2.2.15/lib/mail/message.rb:228:in `deliver'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@global/gems/actionmailer-3.0.3/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:401:in `deliver_mail'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@global/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/messages.rb:52:in `instrument'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@global/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/messages/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
```

...

How to configure **localhost** for ActionMailer?

I searched on internet, it seems I **MUST** provide a **username** and **password** in the configuration, and set **authentication** option to some value, can I configure the ActionMailer without **authentication**, **username** and **password**? (because my app does not have a email account for login)
 how to configure to make localhost email sending feature to work?

Comment: are you running a mail server on your computer?

Comment: Aha, I just found I have 'Thunderbird'

Comment: Yes, at least with the configuration you showed. Let's go a step back, what are you trying to achieve? (I know that is 'send emails' but I need more context)   - EDIT : Thunderbird is an email client, it won't help you in any way.

Comment: In my rails application, a UI button will trigger a function in controller, and that function will send email to user.

Comment: Hi, Augusto, do you mean I have to firstly set up a localhost mail server on my Ubuntu machine?

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your environment.rb:

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :sendmail
ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = true
ActionMailer::Base.default_charset = "utf-8"
```

Comment: Adding this minus the default_charset helped me solve this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

on localhost you should be uusing sendmail, a good start would be this [site](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2007/1/31/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-actionmailer-base-server_settings-deprecated)

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :sendmail
ActionMailer::Base.sendmail_settings = { 
  :location       => '/usr/sbin/sendmail', 
  :arguments      => '-i -t'
}
```

I know the source is old, but seems to be still valid

Answer (score 0):

On localhost you could also use mailtrap. [blog post on mailtrap](http://matt.blogs.it/entries/00002655.html). There is more [documentation here](http://rubymatt.rubyforge.org/mailtrap/). As far as settings go, I put this in my initializer

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :test if Rails.env.test?
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
 :address => "localhost"
 :port => 2525,
 :domain => "localhost",
}
```

This method worked for me.